# Please tell me the beta footer is just for April Fools

Tags: support, beta-sites, footer

Way to mess with my muscle memory!

[image]

It's going back to normal tomorrow right? Right? Please?

Comment: I doubt it.  It's in alphabetical order.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Didn't know "area 51" comes after "writers". Learn something new every day.

Comment: I know. But I hate it.

Comment: Can we have an expander show more button?

Comment: I've seen this footer before, I don't think it's April Fools...

Comment: @LeeLouviere: I hope I don't really have to say this, but the last two are not like the others.

Comment: They have a different color aswell...

Comment: How was it different before? I have no recollection of ever consciously looking at it.

Comment: I seriously don't see that....  So, is this a joke?

Comment: @Seth Are you looking at a beta site?

Comment: Hope you like the redesign better (currently only here, on Meta)

Answer (score 29):

[I asked an expert to remove it](http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/qTYTxKCpD02k).

At first she said she would, but then she admitted she was trying to get rid of it herself.

> User: Not now. I'm trying to get this beta footer to go away.
>
> Expert: Oh really? I'm kind of trying to get this beta footer to go away myself.

So...  She's trying.  We can only hope.

Comment: Must..resist..upvoting joke answer

Comment: Resistance is futile.

Answer (score 19):

At the rate beta sites are getting thrown at the wall it's better to serve up the list of potential new time sinks in alphabetical order. They are all essentially on the same level and equal to each other. Beta is beta is beta.

When you graduate to a full site, then you can expect to be placed in order of second-birth.

Yes, it might do a number on your muscle memory at first, but it's better in the long term for finding a new site to dump your brain into.

Area 51 and Stack Apps, however, are not beta sites.

Comment: I don't even see the beta footer though...

Comment: Y dnt s th bt ftr nlss yr n bt st

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand that language.

Comment: @Seth nl bt sts hv th bt ftr dsplyd.  n rdr t s bt ftr y mst b n bt st.

Comment: @Seth: If you still didn't understand (You don't see the beta footer unless you're on beta site)... I acknowledge that it took me 1 day to decrypt this... Now I am on a mission to decrypt what JNK wrote.. :-)

Comment: @JNK I think we're talking past each other there..

Comment: @JNK Only beta sites have the beta footer displayed. In order to see beta footer you must be on beta site. (Woohoo, only took me 3 minutes :D)

Comment: @Doorknob Give or take 21 days.

Comment: @JNK I just found this question :P

Answer (score 11):

We have gone ahead an implemented a new and improved (!) footer, to be rolled out to all sites, beta or otherwise.

Currently only visible on Meta - hope this won't mess with your muscle memory.

Comment: The new one looks much better and organized.

Comment: They seem to be backwards (S[O/F/U] are at the end of the list).

Comment: @Doorknob - Well spotted. I thought I had that in the right order, but guess not.

Comment: @Oded Instead of just having "more" at the bottom, should we let people click on the headings as well? And the "more" for "others" is essentially "all".

Comment: @Antony - The "more" for "others" is not supposed to be there... Not sure about making the headers links as well. Will bring it up with our UX guy.

Comment: @Doorknob - better? Better.

Comment: If you let the visited links be a different colour than the unvisited links (not by much, but noticeable) then it will help me find my faves. At the moment I'm finding it a challenge, but I'm sure in a week I'll be used to it.

Comment: @KateGregory - I believe in most sites they will be different. It ties into the site theme.

Comment: Very well done!

Answer (score 6):

I can revert the change, if you feel strongly about it.  I couldn't find anything in that morass, which is why I alphabetized them.

Comment: I just had memory of which sites were where, and combined with a colour change I could find them. Now I'm waving my mouse around like an old person. Especially things with The at the beginning. Maybe people could vote for it using this answer?

Comment: Or hopefully [Jin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) can be convinced to finish this design? http://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Ity.png It ties in nicely with the [Stack Exchange Sites page's](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest) categories.

Comment: Wow, I really like that categorized list of sites.

Comment: You have to convince Jin that footer is awesome!

Comment: Yeah!  I really like the new design!

Comment: It's 6-0 for reverting it, and 14-3 for "please tell me it's April Fools" which suggests people other than me want it to go back. Problem is I've retrained my muscle memory already (I do a tour of all "my" sites every morning) so now I don't want it changed back after all :-(

Comment: @KateGregory - The way I do the "tour" is have them bookmarked in their own folder. Middle click that...